# Getting substring from a string based on underscores with regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a middleware tool in which we have an predefined option of using java regular expressions with subStringRegEx( regex , string).

My requirement is to get the required substring between the underscores(_) from given filename( ex: `ABC_XYZ_123_adbc1234-ed98_1234.dat`).

I have tried below 3 ways and all are working when tested with online tools by selecting java. Whereas not working as expected in my tool, I am getting “ABC_XYZ_123_ adbc1234-ed98” instead of only “adbc1234-ed98” value.

1. `(?:[^_]+)_(?:[^_]+)_(?:[^_]+)_([^_]+)`
2. `.*?_.*?_.*?_([^_]+)`
3. `^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_([^_]*)_`

Request your suggestions to achieve the solution.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: why would you want to use regex for this? Just use split("_")

Comment: All 3 patterns work, your value is in capture group 1.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to use [`([^_]+)_[^_]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/9aOaEV/1) instead and grab the value from the capture group?

Comment: Hi Kumar, have you had time to test out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413850/3832970) yet? The first one is generic, the second one is more specific, you may try both to see which one works best for you.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following regex. Value is coming in capture group 1, so do replace with $1 while performing substitution.

```
^(?:.*?_){3}([^_]*)_.*\.dat$
```

[Online Demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/jzqi7k/1)

OR in case format of files could be anything(apart from `.dat`) then try following.

```
^(?:.*?_){3}([^_]*)_.*
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/0LQJ4M/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^(?:.*?_){3}  ##Matching from starting of value, using non greedy match till _ 3 times in a non capturing group.
([^_]*)       ##Creating 1st capturing group which has values till 1st Occurrence of _ in it.
_.*\.dat$     ##Matching from _ to till dat at the end of value.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?:[^_]+_){3}([^_]+).*
```

and replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT0GQz/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^_]+_){3}` - three occurrences of any one or more chars other than `_` and then a `_` char
- `([^_]+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): one or more chars other than `_`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Another idea:

```java
^.*_([^_]+)_[0-9]+\.[^._]*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT0GQz/2), and you will still need to replace with `$1`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any text (not including line break chars, as many as possible)
- `_` - a `_` char
- `([^_]+)` - one or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - a `_` char
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `\.` - a `.` char (NOTE: `\` might need doubling)
- `[^._]*` - any zero or more chars other than `.` and `_`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, all 3 patterns work but you have to get the value from group 1.

Example

```
String patterns[] = { 
    "(?:[^_]+)_(?:[^_]+)_(?:[^_]+)_([^_]+)", 
    ".*?_.*?_.*?_([^_]+)",
    "^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_([^_]*)_"
};

String s = "ABC_XYZ_123_adbc1234-ed98_1234.dat";

for (String p : patterns) {
    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output

```
adbc1234-ed98
adbc1234-ed98
adbc1234-ed98
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/t9Tkya).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the String methods to achieve this:

```js
const str = "ABC_XYZ_123_adbc1234-ed98_1234.dat"

const charSet = str.substr(0, str.length-4).split("_").join("")
console.log(charSet)
```

Comment: You are missing the fact that "*we have an predefined option of using java regular expressions with `subStringRegEx( regex , string)`.*"

Comment: This post had `javascript` tag, now i see it's only java related :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the spec for `subStringRegEx (regex, string)`, but if it returns a substring (`$0`) in `string` that matches `regex`, then it should be

```
String regex = "[^_]+(?=_[^_]*$)";
```